# Sort multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the following array which I want to sort based on the "lastfirma" value. So the following array:

```
Array
(
    [000002] => Array
        (
            [clients] => Array
                (
                    [556046-2222] => Array
                        (
                            [lastfirma] => Name 1
                            [periods] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 000015
                                            [start] => 2020-05-01
                                            [end] => 2021-04-30
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 105779
                                            [start] => 2021-05-01
                                            [end] => 2022-04-30
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [556892-1111] => Array
                        (
                            [lastfirma] => Anomaly
                             [periods] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 000015
                                            [start] => 2020-05-01
                                            [end] => 2021-04-30
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 105779
                                            [start] => 2021-05-01
                                            [end] => 2022-04-30
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

would become

```
Array
(
    [000002] => Array
        (
            [clients] => Array
                (
                    [556892-1111] => Array
                        (
                            [lastfirma] => Anomaly
                             [periods] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 000015
                                            [start] => 2020-05-01
                                            [end] => 2021-04-30
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 105779
                                            [start] => 2021-05-01
                                            [end] => 2022-04-30
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [556046-2222] => Array
                        (
                            [lastfirma] => Name 1
                            [periods] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 000015
                                            [start] => 2020-05-01
                                            [end] => 2021-04-30
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [userId] => 105779
                                            [start] => 2021-05-01
                                            [end] => 2022-04-30
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: What's your question about this? What did you try to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Tried to apply the following after searching solutions but believe I want to sort on a key further down the dimension it doesn't work:

$key_values = array_column($newarray, 'lastfirma'); 
array_multisort($key_values, SORT_ASC, $newarray);

Comment: Also tried the following suggestion:  array_multisort(array_map(function($element) {
   return $element[4]['lastfirma'];
  }, $newarray), SORT_ASC, $newarray);

Comment: @KevinLindmark Always share `var_export` of your input data in your question.

Comment: `uasort($data['000002']['clients'], fn($a, $b) => strcmp($a['lastfirma'], $b['lastfirma']));`

Comment: https://3v4l.org/c5FIq

Comment: If you want to share new details about your problems, please add them to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uasort(
  $input['000002']['clients'],
  static fn($item1, $item2) => $item1['lastfirma'] <=> $item2['lastfirma']
);
```

If there is more than one key on the first level ('000002', '000003', ...), then wrap it in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($input as &$item) {
  uasort(
    $item['clients'],
    static fn($item1, $item2) => $item1['lastfirma'] <=> $item2['lastfirma']
  );
}
unset($item);
```

Note the reference variable &$item, and the unsetting of the last reference after the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this would be to use [`uasort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
uasort($array['000002']['clients'], fn ($a, $b) => strcmp($a['lastfirma'], $b['lastfirma']));
```

The above assumes that the `lastfirma` value is a string value and sorts the clients array by this value in ascending order and maintain index association.

Comment: Have you tried this code?

Comment: Yes I have? Is it not working?

Comment: Not with OPs data...

Comment: Now it should work, my test data had one extra level =)

Comment: All good now...